# Einstein tensor in Schwarzschild spacetime

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature, spacetime-dimensions

If we consider a metric in $n$-dimensional spacetime 
$$d s^2=-(1-f(r)) dt^2+(1-f(r))^{-1}d r^2+r^2 d\Omega_{n-2}^2,$$
what is the Einstein tensor, $G_{\mu\nu}=R_{\mu\nu}-R g_{\mu\nu}/2$, expressed in terms of $f(r)$? Is there a quick way to calculate this?

Comment: the quickest way is the one shown here: http://f.yukterez.net/einstein.equations/files/2.html but for Schwarzschild it is 0

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Mathematica. The package GRQUICK.m https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8329/ is a good one to compute the Ricci tensor and scalar. If you develop your own code and learn how to use the package you will be able to compute geometric objects very fast.